# Slack 3.4.2 not opening on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: slack

I tried installing the .deb file from the Slack website and installing via snap. (Running `sudo apt remove slack-desktop` in between)

But both times nothing happens when I try to run slack from the terminal.
When I search for and run slack in the dash, the icon shows up in the launcher and flashes a few times, then it disappears.

I found information on libnode.so, but I don't think my problem is the same for the following reasons:

- I'm using 16.04, not 18
- I get no messages after trying to run slack from the terminal:
  [terminal after attempting to run slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUd8D.png)

The app works fine on another Ubuntu 16.04 build on a different computer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if it work on one computer and not the other, please provide the exact model number of both laptops, if it's a desktop provide the hardware specifications.